# Zooming slideshow in JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, zooming

On a current project, we want a slideshow on the start page, cycling through the images on a steady pase. So far so good.

But the customer requests a slow zoom on the images between the transitions as well. It's available in Flash and has been used for quite some time, example on the link below:

http://activeden.net/item/xml-zooming-slideshow/9577

But I want this in JS/jQuery.. Does anyone know of a plugin that will do this, or has written one before that could get us started?

All help appreciated!

Best regards
Niclas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called the ["Ken Burns effect"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Burns_effect).

See: http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/

I don't recommend using *any* JavaScript implementation of this effect - they all appear to "wobble" unpleasantly in certain browsers.

Comment: Thanks alot!! That's EXACTLY right! Can't believe I didn't think of the name Ken Burns.. You really helped me out here! I'll concider the wobble effect, but right now this is awesome!

Comment: Yeah the wobble got really appearent.. Damn JS with no anti aliasing!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you

http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/image-zoom/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that's not the effect we're after.. It was the Ken Burns effect we needed.